# wordpress directory file ownership changes everytime after uploading files/plugins

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, wordpress

on centos 7, i have created wordpress website with root directory ownership **websitename:websitegroup** and directory permissions **755**, file permissions **644** set by default

when the developer, login to wordpress dashboard and tried to upload something to media or install plugins, the wp says no write permission,

then i had to give g+w permissions to wp root directory, then he able to install plugin or upload media.

after uploading the media  the uploaded plugin/media permission changes to **apache:apache** from **websitename:websitegroup**

**how to avoid?**

1. Me giving g+x permissions to wp root directory to let the developer to install plugins/upload media
2. and the ownership of any upload from wp dashboar shouldn't changed to apache:apache

**what i tried**

Currently i found no alternative to stop this, eveytime i had to give g+w permissions and revert them back after developer work

Answer (score 0):

The web server (or the PHP process, depending on your setup) needs write access to the directory. The only feasable way is to run said process as the user `websitename`.

Principally another option would be to give the user `apache` write permissions via ACL or by adding it to the `websitegroup` group, but that would also result in the uploaded files being owned by `apache`. If you want all files and folders being owned by `websitename` you need to run the webserver as that user.

Comment: You should not need to run the web server as the user, but PHP. PHP-FPM with per-user pools is suitable for this, which would also prevent Wordpress sites on the same host from writing to each other's directories. `apache` should still have read permissions to serve static files. This would be possible with `websitename:apache` & `640`.

Comment: i understand the first part that need to configure "per-user pool", but what is "websitename:apache & 640" again? after using per-user pool, am i not able to user websitename:websitegroup ownership on whole website? why do i still need to use root as group?

Comment: If you run the websever as a user it does not run as root anymore and normal filesystem permissions apply. The permissions suggested by Esa would allow write permissions to the PHP-FPM process (assuming you are using it and it is running as the user `websitename`) and read permissions to the Apache process (running as a user with the group `apache`)

Answer (score 0):

Your description of how this is provisioned is not helpful. Lets start from scratch.

Users:

- apache - the uid your PHP runtime executes as
- dev1, dev2, dev2 - developers
- backup - for creating backups of the site
- support[n] - for investigating issues

Due to the way Wordpress is designed its very difficult to operate unless "apache" has full read/write access to the site.

If all the management is done via the web UI, the developers do need *any* access to the files in the document root. However I have seen sites where devs routinely use CLI access to updated files. So lets assume they need read/write access.

Backup uids need read only access to the files.

Support need read only access to the files.

That just leaves the site user. This is your construct. In the absence of additional information about how you are using this, it appears to be entirely redundant.

So the only classes of access are read+write and read-only. But just for the fun of it, we'll say there is an additional class with no-access - and call this user "alien".

User ownership is always determined by the uid creating a file - and is single-valued per user. So we can't use that as a mechanism for permitting access.

Users can however belong to multiple groups, and each group can have multiple users. So we can associate the read-write privilege with a specific group. Call it webupdate.

That leaves read-only access (backup and support) - which can be provided via the "other" permission bits.

But how then do you exclude "alien"? By placing the site in a directory which alien has no access to - that means we need another group which identifies people who have *some* access. Call this webaccess.

So the group membership:

- webupdate: apache, dev1, dev2...devn
- webaccess:  apache, dev1, dev2...devn, backup, support[n]

then we have the directories, permissions and ownership:

```
drwxr-x--- root:webaccess /var/www/SITENAME
drwxrwxr-x ????:webupdate /var/www/SITENAME/html  (document root)
```

All well and good, but when someone in "webupdate" creates a new file or directory in the document root, the group ownership will be their DEFAULT group - not webupdate. You can change this behaviour with the setgid bit on directories:

```
drwxrwSr-x ????:webupdate /var/www/SITENAME/html
```

The last part of the puzzle is to ensure that the umask is set to 00x for members of webupdate so new files and directories acquire the correct permissions). Don't forget to set this in your sshd_config for the sftp server as well as for interactive shells.

Hence once you have the groups in place, you can run:

```
chown -R apache:webupdate  /var/www/SITENAME/html
chmod -r g+s /var/www/SITENAME/html
```

And thats it - you should never have to fix the permissions again.

Comment: Thank you, now i got clear picture of it and sorry i am not able up vote to you people  as need at least 15 reputation

Comment: As I told in the comments of the other answer, this approach has security consequences: every Wordpress site would be able to write over the files on other Wordpress sites & read the database credentials, too. In other words: if one of the sites is hacked, all of them must be considered compromised. Using separate users & PHP-FPM pools per site reduces this significantly.

Comment: If you are running wordpress, you don't care about security. But there are multiple ways to improve the security of a multi-tenant installation - this model is the basis for at least three of them